# Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use). Object wont init and Push error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, heap, push

In advanced, let me thank your for looking at this code for me, because it has been bugging me for a while now and I can't seem to find the issue.

Whenever I run it, it doesn't throw any errors within the console, instead it throws this error:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: [Filepath to .exe]
>   File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
>   Line 892
>
> Expression: is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)

I've been trying to figure it out, but it just wont work for me. I believe it has something to do with the template types I am passing in, as it only crashes whenever I try to initialize a minHeap object or try my Push method, which I also believe is an issue.

Once again, thank you all so much for looking at my code.

Main:

```
#include "minHeap.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Node<char> A = Node<char>(0, 'A');
    Node<char> B = Node<char>(1, 'B');
    Node<char> C = Node<char>(2, 'C');
    Node<char> D = Node<char>(3, 'D');

    minHeap<char> myHeap = minHeap<char>();

    //Below doesn't work, something about subscript is not of integrap type
    //myHeap.push(A.index, A.value);
    //myHeap.push(B.index, B.value);
    //myHeap.push(C.index, C.value);
    //myHeap.push(D.index, D.value);

    cout << A.index << endl;

    myHeap.~minHeap();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is Node.h:

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    float index;
    T value;

    Node(float indx, T val);
    ~Node();
};

template<typename T>
inline Node<T>::Node(float indx, T val)
{
    index = indx;
    value = val;
}

template<typename T>
inline Node<T>::~Node()
{
}
```

And finally, minHeap:

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class minHeap
{
private:
    T* arr[100];
    int arrSize = 0;

    void heapifyUp(int indx);
    void heapifyDown(int indx);
    int getParent(int indx);
    int childLeft(int indx);
    int childRight(int indx);
    int swap(int indxA, int indxB);

public:
    minHeap();
    ~minHeap();

    void push(int indx, T val);
    void pop();
};

template<typename T>
inline minHeap<T>::minHeap()
{
}

template<typename T>
inline minHeap<T>::~minHeap()
{
    delete[] arr;
}

template<typename T>
inline void minHeap<T>::heapifyUp(int indx)
{
    if (indx <= 0) return;
    int j = getParent(indx);
    if (arr[indx] < arr[j]) {
        int temp = arr[indx];
        arr[indx] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
    heapifyUp(j);
}

template<typename T>
inline void minHeap<T>::heapifyDown(int indx)
{
    int j;

    //if no left child
    if (childLeft(indx) > arrSize - 1) return;

    //if no right child
    if (childRight(indx) > arrSize - 1) j = childLeft(indx);

    //No children
    else j = (arr[childLeft(indx)] < arr[childRight(indx)]) ? (childLeft(indx)):(childRight(indx));

    if (arr[indx] > arr[indx]) {
        int temp = arr[indx];
        arr[indx] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
    heapifyDown(j);
}

template<typename T>
inline int minHeap<T>::getParent(int indx)
{
    return (indx - 1) / 2;
}

template<typename T>
inline int minHeap<T>::childLeft(int indx)
{
    return 2 * i + 1;
}

template<typename T>
inline int minHeap<T>::childRight(int indx)
{
    return 2 * i + 2;
}

template<typename T>
inline int minHeap<T>::swap(int indxA, int indxB)
{
    int tempA = arr[indxA];
    int tempB = arr[indxB];

    arr[indxA] = tempB;
    arr[indxB] = tempA;

    return 0;
}

template<typename T>
inline void minHeap<T>::push(int indx, T val)
{

    //Something with Array is broken. Fix it pupper
    int tempVal = arr[indx];
    arr[indx] = val;
    arrSize += 1;
    heapifyUp(arrSize - 1);
}

template<typename T>
inline void minHeap<T>::pop()
{
    int temp = arr[0];

    arr[0] = arr[arrSize - 1];
    arr[arrSize - 1] = nullptr;
    arrSize -= 1;
    heapifyDown(0);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you visited the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)? Are you familiar with the concept of a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `myHeap.~minHeap();`?  This results in `myHeap` being destroyed twice, with the second call trying to free memory that has already been freed.  This can cause the error you're seeing.

You can construct your variables a lot more concisely:

```
Node<char> A(0, 'A');
minHeap<char> myHeap;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I edited what you suggested, however the error still appears even after the removal of the myHeap.~minHeap();

Comment: There are numerous problems in this code; I pointed out the most obvious one.  Another related one is that you declare `T *arr[100];`, which is an array of pointers to T, then in the destructor call `delete[] arr;` which is not valid since arr is an array and hasn't been allocated with `new`.  (You only `delete` something that you allocate with `new`.)